# zend array[] element with validator

Tags: zend-framework, forms

hello i have a form where the user can click on a button and dinamically add new elements(with Jquery)

```
<input name="sconto[]" type="text"><br>
<input name="sconto[]" type="text"><br>
<input name="sconto[]" type="text"><br>
...
```

I have a custom validator for float numbers in format with comma and dot separation like 20.50 and 20,50
The problem is i can't seem to find how to make zend apply it it to each element of the array.

So how should i declare this element and how to apply the validator? xD

this is my validator

```
protected $_messageTemplates = array(
self::NON_E_NUMERO  => 'non sembra essere un numero'
);

public function isValid($value, $context = null)
{
    $pos_virgola = strpos($value, ",");
    if ($pos_virgola !== false)
        $value = str_replace(",", ".", $value);

    if (!is_numeric($value))
    {
        $this->_error(self::NON_E_NUMERO, $value);
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}
```

}

the form i don't know how to do it, i use this but obviously it doesn't work

```
$sconto = $this->createElement('text','sconto')->setLabel('sconto');
//->setValidators(array(new Gestionale_Validator_Float()));
$this->addElement($sconto);
...
$sconto->setDecorators(array(//no ViewHelper
            'Errors',
            'Description',
            array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td', /*'class' => 'valore_campo', */'id'=>'sconto')),
            array('TdLabel', array('placement' => 'prepend', 'class' => 'nome_campo'))
    ));
```

Comment: Can you provide code for the form and your validator.

Comment: I think that in ZF you cannot easily make forms with multiple  fields named 'sconto[]'. However you could do 'sconto[0]', 'sconto[1]', etc. Have a look for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405897/zend-form-array-based-elements) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922304/array-input-like-name-person-in-zend-form/4923019#4923019).

Comment: i could do sconto[0] sconto[1] ... with javascript, the problem is i don't know how many the user will enter

Comment: Yeah, these things are why I prefer handling my forms and my $_POST data myself. I just hope that Zend_Form will live up to the rest of Zend Framework in version 2.

Answer (score 1):

If Marcin comment is not what you want to do, then this is another way to create multi text element.

1. Create a custom decorator 'My_Form_Decorator_MultiText'. You will need to register your custom decorator class. Read Zend Framework doc for details http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.decorators.html

   class My_Form_Decorator_MultiText extends Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract {

   ```
   public function render($content) {

       $element = $this->getElement();
       if (!$element instanceof Zend_Form_Element_Text) {
           return $content;
       }

       $view = $element->getView();
       if (!$view instanceof Zend_View_Interface) {
           return $content;
       }

       $values = $element->getValue();
       $name = $element->getFullyQualifiedName();
       $html = '';

       if (is_array($values)) {
           foreach ($values as $value) {
               $html .= $view->formText($name, $value);
           }
       } else {
           $html = $view->formText($name, $values);
       }

       switch ($this->getPlacement()) {
           case self::PREPEND:
               return $html . $this->getSeparator() . $content;
           case self::APPEND:
           default:
               return $content . $this->getSeparator() . $html;
       }
   }
   ```

   }
2. Now your validation class will validate each element value

   class My_Validate_Test extends Zend_Validate_Abstract {
       const NON_E_NUMERO = 'numero';
       protected $_messageTemplates = array(
           self::NON_E_NUMERO => 'non sembra essere un numero'
       );

   ```
   public function isValid($value, $context = null) {
       if (!is_numeric($value)) {
           $this->_error(self::NON_E_NUMERO, $value);
           return false;
       }
       else
           return true;
   }
   ```

   }
3. This is how you can use the new decorator

`$element = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('sconto', array(
                'validators' => array(
                    new My_Validate_Test(),
                ),
                'decorators' => array(
                    'MultiText', // new decorator
                    'Label',
                    'Errors',
                    'Description',
                    array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'dl',))
                ),
                'label' => 'sconto',
                'isArray' => true // must be true
            ));
    $this->addElement($element);`

Hope this helps

Comment: i don't understand why this is suppose to work with an arbitrary length array, it seeems to me that the validator is passed only one value ?

Comment: Your are not clear of what you want. Creating an array elements or adding new elements with JavaScript in Zend_Form is easy. You have different answers posted by other member and I posted another option. All of the answers will achieve the same result array elements. Good Luck!