# Zend form input name with same name

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

Using Zend 1.9 I am trying to generate a form using Zend Form module .
My form should be like this:

```
<form method="post" action="myaction">

    <input type="text" name="editors[]" />
    <input type="text" name="editors[]" />
    <input type="text" name="editors[]" />
    <input type="text" name="editors[]" />

    <button type="submit" >Go</button>

</form>
```

When I submit the form in my controller I want to see something like this:

```
Zend_Debug::dump($this->getAllParams());

//I expect this output:
array (size=4)
  'controller' => string 'myCotnroller' (length=8)
  'module' => string 'MyModule' (length=14)
  'action' => string 'test' (length=4)
  'editors' => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string '' (length=3)
      1 => string '' (length=0)
      2 => string '' (length=0)
      3 => string '' (length=0)
```

I the last week I tried many and many times with no result. I have search whitout any goog result .
Can you help  me?

Comment: What result are you actually getting?

Comment: I am using belongsTo property and/or isArray property without any good result. Why my question is downvoted? I searched in StackOverflow db but no people have a good ask for this question.

Comment: What is the output you are actually getting? You have given us what is expected but you haven't shown us what you are currently getting.

Comment: Actually I am getting no output becouse when I build the elements off the form there is no property to do my task. So I am blocked. This is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029532/associated-array-elements-in-zend-form/3424766#3424766

Comment: An othe similar question without a clear response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922304/array-input-like-name-person-in-zend-form

Answer (score 0):

I hope some of these will help on your quest.
 [Zend Framework: Working with Form elements in array notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672689/zend-framework-working-with-form-elements-in-array-notation)
[Advanced Zend_Form Usage](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.advanced.html)
[Zend_Form - Array based elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405897/zend-form-array-based-elements)
[How do configure Zend_Form to use array notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928551/how-do-configure-zend-form-to-use-array-notation)